# Increment value for unique key column

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, unique-constraint

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rank BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY rank (rank)
)
```

With some values:

```
(2,    11)
(1,    12)
(9,    42)
(4711, 43)
(9000, 44)
```

I.e the ranks may have gaps. The rank is always >= 1.

**I want to increment every rank by one, starting by the 3rd least value:**

```
UPDATE tbl table_1
JOIN (
    SELECT table_2.id
    FROM tbl table_2
    ORDER BY table_2.rank ASC
    LIMIT 2, 18446744073709551615
) sub_1 ON table_1.id = sub_1.id
SET table_1.rank = table_1.rank + 1
```

Problem:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '43' for key 'rank'

---

What I have tried:

- Adding `ORDER BY`:

  ```
  UPDATE tbl table_1
  JOIN (
      SELECT table_2.id
      FROM tbl table_2
      ORDER BY table_2.rank ASC
      LIMIT 2, 18446744073709551615
  ) sub_1 ON table_1.id = sub_1.id
  SET table_1.rank = table_1.rank + 1
  ORDER BY table_1.rank DESC
  ```

  > #1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY
- Eliminating the join:

  ```
  UPDATE tbl
  SET rank = rank + 1
  WHERE rank >= (
      SELECT table_2.rank
      FROM tbl table_2
      ORDER BY table_2.rank ASC
      LIMIT 2, 1
  )
  ORDER BY rank DESC
  ```

  > #1093 - Table 'tbl' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

---

The only options I can think of are either omitting `UNIQUE KEY`, or splitting up the statement into two: get the 3rd least rank, then run `UPDATE  … ORDER BY …`.

Is there any proper solution for my problem?

---

Server: MariaDB 10.2.15
InnoDB: 5.7.22

Comment: I would **strongly** advise you to change the name of your `rank` field to something else (my_rank, the_rank, tbl_rank...) because with MySQL ([8.02 and above](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/)), `RANK` is now a keyword (for analytic/window functions). Best to avoid this if possible!

Comment: @Vérace, thank you for the hint! The actual statements are generated by sqlalchemy, which will \`quote\` names when needed.

Comment: There must be a table with a field called `rank` though? Or have I misunderstood the ORM - whatever else confusing they did, I didn't think they renamed fields!

Comment: @Vérace, no I could give it any name. (How about "index"? ;) ) I meant that sqlalchemy automatically escapes names using backticks when you use a reserved name, so you don't have to think for too long how you call your columns. The name "rank" makes sense semantically, that's why I chose it. But beware: Java's Hibernate does rename columns instead of escaping the names. (At least it did a few years ago when I used it.)

Comment: Indeed - but what happens when you want to port? Avoid all 825 words [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) and you'll be fine :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think You can perform update You need using 2 statements.

1) Update all records in decreasing order. Single-table UPDATE allows ordering.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET rank=rank+1
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

2) Restore values for first 2 records.

```
UPDATE tbl
SET rank=rank-1
ORDER BY rank ASC LIMIT 2;
```